# Passing images between Activity

Tags: android, android-image

A bitmap is captured and passed between Activity by declaring static.

### For the first time, the images can be displayed. However, when the second Activity is destroyed and created again, the image cannot be shown. The error is:

```
04-30 12:55:28.988: W/dalvikvm(4034): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@40531360, 800x480
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:973)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1062)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:332)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:943)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7014)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7126)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7017)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2054)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1632)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1335)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1991)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
04-30 12:55:29.028: E/AndroidRuntime(4034):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass it using a static variable,  this rules apply to sharing data (which isn't final) between activities in general.

Instead, pass it in the intent bundle:

```
intent.putExtra("a bitmap", myBitmap);
```

If this is a big image, you might want to store it to a file and pass the file path in the intent.

Comment: I dont want to save to sd card and read it from another activity since it might slower the frame rate using IO in a thread. However, I cannot apply "openFileOutput" in run to write in internal memory, i dont know why!

Answer (score 0):

Error -

> trying to use a recycled bitmap

This error occurs when you are trying to access the recycled Bitmap. So, might be you are using `bitmap.recycle();` and then try to use the same bitmap which is not possible, you can't use the recycled Bitmap again. It would be better to create a new Bitmap from that or manage not to recycle the Bitmap.

Comment: I did not use bitmap.recycled so sometimes the bitmap can show and sometimes not. Is it possible that it is automatically recycled during swapping of activity?

Since I am using thread, I tried to put the image into internal memory but it cannot recognize openFileOutput inside run

Please give me some suggestion! thanks!!